# Calling delayed performSelector: on a static instance from an NSThread?

Tags: objective-c, static, selector

HI, I have a static NSMutableArray* staticArray in an NSOperation subclass (in myOperation.m) and a method:

> static NSMutableArray *staticArray =
>   nil;
>
> +(void) initialize {
>
> ```
> staticArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
> ```
>
> }

```
-(void) addStrToStaticArray:(NSString*)aStr {
    if([staticArray indexOfObject:aStr] == NSNotFound) {
        [staticArray addObject:aStr];
        [staticArray performSelector:@selector(removeObject:)
                          withObject:aStr
                          afterDelay:30.];
    }
}
```

I call the above method and after that the operation finishes execution. The problem is that aStr is never removed from the array. What am I missing ? Thanks...

Comment: performSelector:...afterDelay: schedules the selector to be executed on the **current** thread,, witch does not exists any more afterDelay:30. I think this is the problem! So I am trying to find an efficient way to schedule a selector to be performed on the main thread **after a delay**. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use timer (CFRunLoopTimer/NSTimer) and run loop (CFRunLoop/NSRunLoop) apis to accomplish this.

in that case, you create a timer, and add it to the main run loop.

this would also require that you create a function or method for your timer to call. if you choose a method, you could use an NSInvocation instead (if that's what you prefer).

since the data is static, and the operation (presumably) won't exist, you can message via a class method.

Answer (score 1):

Based to Justin suggestions, I can now delayed remove an object from an array invoking the method from inside a NSThread, NSOperation despite their existence at the time of the removal:

```
NSMethodSignature * mySignature = [NSMutableArray instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(removeObject:)];
NSInvocation * myInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:mySignature];
[myInvocation setTarget:staticArray];
[myInvocation setSelector:@selector(removeObject:)];
[myInvocation setArgument:&aStr atIndex:2];

//At this point, myInvocation is a complete object, describing a message that can be sent.

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:90.
                                     invocation:myInvocation 
                                        repeats:NO];

if(timer) {
    NSRunLoop *mainRL = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];
    [mainRL addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

The aStr will be removed from staticArray after 90 seconds. For details...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/Tasks/invocations.html